# Unexpected split behavior

Tags: awk, posix, gawk, mawk

I read about Awk split behavior here:

> [...] the *fs* argument to the **split** function (see String Functions) shall
>   be interpreted as extended regular expressions. These can be either **ERE**
>   tokens or arbitrary expressions, and shall be interpreted in the same manner
>   as the right-hand side of the `~` or `!~` operator.

and:

> If the right-hand operand is any expression other than the lexical token
>   **ERE**, the string value of the expression shall be interpreted as an
>   extended regular expression, including the escape conventions described above.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04

However I have noticed an unexpected result, with this code:

```
BEGIN {
  print split("te.st", q, ".")
}
```

I would expect the `.` to represent any character, and for the result to be `6`.
However all my tests returned `2`. Running this code gives the expected `6`:

```
BEGIN {
  print split("te.st", q, /./)
}
```

Tested with:

- gawk
- gawk --posix
- mawk 1.3.4
- mawk 1.3.3
- nawk (original-awk)

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or is this an error?

Comment: It is usuall regex to be entered in`/.../` format. It is also described in gawk documentation here (scroll down to split function): https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to GNU awk and its docs have been [changed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/?id=7eac08335f61dc6b0f236f9bf7c3ad434576b70f) to mention this behavior explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error; it's just that the standard isn't clear enough while trying to codify the existing practice.

The mawk(1) manual is more explicit:

> `split(expr, A, sep)` works as follows:
>
> ...
>
> (2) If `sep = " "` (a single space), then `<SPACE>` is trimmed from the
>   front and back of `expr`, and `sep` becomes `<SPACE>`. mawk defines
>   `<SPACE>` as the regular expression `/[ \t\n]+/`.
>   Otherwise `sep` is treated as a regular expression, **except that
>   meta-characters are ignored for a string of length 1**, e.g.,
>   `split(x, A, "*")` and `split(x, A, /*/)` are the same.

Also, the GNU awk manual from the [current sources](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/doc/gawk.1?h=gawk-4.2-stable&id=7eac08335f61dc6b0f236f9bf7c3ad434576b70f#n3086):

> `split(s, a [, r [, seps] ])`
>
> ...
>
> Splitting behaves   identically   to   field   splitting, described above.
>   In particular, if `r` is a single-character string, that string acts  as
>   the separator,  even  if it happens to be a regular expression
>   metacharacter.

This is the description from the susv4 [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

> An extended regular expression can be used to separate fields by assigning a
>   string containing the expression to the built-in variable **FS**, either
>   directly or as a consequence of using the `-F sepstring` option. The
>   default value of the **FS** variable shall be a single <space>. The
>   following describes **FS** behavior:
>
> 1. If **FS** is a null string, the behavior is unspecified.
> 2. If **FS** is a **single character**:
>
>    a. If **FS** is <space>, skip leading and trailing <blank> and
>      <newline> characters; fields shall be delimited by sets of one or
>      more <blank> or <newline> characters.
>
>    b. Otherwise, if **FS** is any other character c, **fields shall be delimited
>      by each single occurrence of c**.
> 3. Otherwise, the string value of **FS** shall be considered to be an
>      extended regular expression. Each occurrence of a sequence matching the
>      extended regular expression shall delimit fields.

Your example matches 2.b.

Even if that explicitly mentions `FS`, it's same behavior with any argument used
instead of it as the 3rd argument to `split` in all awk implementations, including in the case where that argument is a space.

It's unlikely that behavior will ever change, because the `FS` variable is just a string (`awk` doesn't have regexp objects, like `javascript` or `perl`; you cannot assign a regexp to a variable, as in `a=/./` or `$a=qr/./`); it's the `split` function (called either implicitly or explicitly) which does interpret its argument as described above.

The origin of this behavior may be compatibility with the "old" awk, where `FS` (or the 3rd argument to `split`) was always treated as a single character. Example (on unix v7):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="."; print split("foo.bar.baz", a, "bar"); print a[2] }'
3
ar.
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="."; print split("foo.bar.baz", a, /bar/); print a[2] }'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
Bus error - core dumped
```

Comment: Not that using `.` as a regex to split on makes much sense anyway, it would destroy the string and return the number of characters plus one, and there are easier ways to get that. I don't think there are other single-character REs that would make sense here either (but I might be wrong).

Comment: `awk -F'|'`, `awk -F.`, `awk -F+`, `awk -F'$'`, `awk -F'^'`, `awk -F'\'` are common. Note that in the original `awk`, `awk -Ft` meant _split on tab_ (back then as you say, only the first character was used). That's one case where backward compatibility was not maintained with nawk. Here, with POSIX `awk`, you can always use `FS = "(.)"` for FS to be the regexp matching a single character (`.{1}` would also work but is less portable).