# Why does regex `"\.pdf"` match `/.../pdf.../...` in gawk, but not in mawk?

Tags: awk, regular-expression, gawk, mawk

From [How can I extract only the pid column and only the pathname column in the lsof output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500977/how-can-i-extract-only-the-pid-column-and-only-the-pathname-column-in-the-lsof-o#comment923072_500984)

```
awk '{ for (i=9; i<=NF; i++) {
    if ($i ~ "string" && $1 != "wineserv" && $5 == "REG" && $NF ~ "\.pdf") {
        $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""
        print
    }
}}'
```

The regex `"\.pdf"` matches `/.../pdf.../...` in gawk, but not in mawk. I wonder why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it's about the regex, but about how the double-quoted string is handled. C-style escapes (like `\n`) are interpreted in awk strings, and gawk and mawk treat invalid escapes differently:

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN { print "\."; }'
\.
$ gawk 'BEGIN { print "\."; }'
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\.' treated as plain `.'
.
```

That is, mawk seems to leave the backslash as-is, while gawk removes it (and complains, at least in my version). So, the actual regexes used are *different*: in gawk the regex is `.pdf`, which of course matches `/pdf`, since the dot matches any single character, while in mawk your regex is `\.pdf`, where the dot is escaped and matched literally.

[GNU awk's manual explicitly mentions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html#Escape-Sequences) it's not portable to use a backslash before a character with no defined backslash-escape sequence (see the box "Backslash Before Regular Characters"):

> If you place a backslash in a string constant before something that is not one of the characters previously listed, POSIX awk purposely leaves what happens as undefined. There are two choices:
>
> **Strip the backslash out**
> This is what BWK awk and gawk both do. For example, `"a\qc"` is the same as `"aqc"`.
> **Leave the backslash alone**
> Some other awk implementations do this. In such implementations, typing `"a\qc"` is the same as typing `"a\\qc"`.

I assume you want the dot to be escaped in the regex, so the safe ways are either `$NF ~ "\\.pdf"`, or `$NF ~ /\.pdf/` (since with the regex literal `/.../`, the escapes aren't "double processed").

The [POSIX text](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04) also notes the double processing of the escapes:

> If the right-hand operand *[of `~` or `!~`]* is any expression other than the lexical token ERE, the string value of the expression shall be interpreted as an extended regular expression, including the escape conventions described above. Note that **these same escape conventions shall also be applied in determining the value of a string literal** (the lexical token STRING), and thus **shall be applied a second time when a string literal is used** in this context.

So, this works in both gawk and mawk:

```
$ ( echo .pdf; echo /pdf ) |
  awk '{ if ($0 ~ "\\.pdf") print "   match: " $0; else print "no match: " $0; }'
   match: .pdf
no match: /pdf
```

as does this:

```
$ ( echo .pdf; echo /pdf ) |
  awk '{ if ($0 ~ /\.pdf/) print "   match: " $0; else print "no match: " $0; }'
   match: .pdf
no match: /pdf
```

Comment: See also http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105 There's going to be some changes in that regard in the next POSIX version.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I was hoping you'd have a clarification. (I thought about making a proper Q out of it, but didn't get that done.) But the text in that bug report is still a bit too much standardese for me... Should that update on the escape characters table be understood so that in `/\[/`, `\[` stays as-is, and then the backslash makes the `[` lose it's special properties during the regex processing? So that the intention indeed is that `/\[/` does the same as `\[` in grep etc?

Comment: `[.]` is a more readable way to match a dot as @mosvy mentions below.

Answer (score 5):

As you see from the table [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04), in a regular expression in awk, a backslash not followed by up to 3 octal digits, another backslash or any of the `["/abfnrtv]` is undefined.

Your best bet is to write `[.]` instead of `\.` if you want a literal `.`.

Notice that in this case, it's `mawk`'s behavior which is off wrt general practice; while all `awk`'s implementations I know of will let you escape `\.`, `\+`, `\*` inside a regex literal (`/foo\.bar/`), only `mawk` will let you do the same inside a string used as a regular expression (`$0~"foo\.bar"`).

Comment: and, depending on what info you need, using `/proc` or `sock_diag` directly from perl or python may be a better idea than parsing the output of `lsof`.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. Above the table it says _"The awk utility shall make use of the extended regular expression notation [link] except that it shall allow the use of C-language conventions for escaping special characters"_ and behind the link _"An ERE special character [...] when preceded by a <backslash>, such a character shall be an ERE that matches the special character itself."_. I don't think the first sentence is supposed to mean that the table there should override the usual meaning of the backslash in ERE.

Comment: It does say _"The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> is undefined"_, but then the dot is explicitly listed as a special character. Here, the backslash works fine in escaping the dot (in all versions of awk I can find): `echo '/pdf \.pdf' |mawk '$1 ~ $2 { print "match"; }'`

Comment: that table is pretty clear (any backslash followed by a character not in this table or the \n, \r, etc => undefined). That table is also referenced from the description of the STRING token. Anyways, that spec should codify existing practice and, here mawk is the odd one.

Comment: hmm yes, that's a rather interesting contradiction. I wonder, is there some awk implementation that would take that table to the letter, and treat e.g. `\[`, `\*` or `\(` as something other than escaped special characters?

Comment: The awk spec in susv4 has a lot of defects, eg. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483874/308316). It also doesn't mention that a `split` (either implicit or explicit) will create dual string/number values, unlike other funcs or assignments (that's only vaguely and carefully alluded to ;-)). All in all, I don't see anything to change to my little answer to this trivial question: it tells the standard specified and the actual real-life behavior, and recommends the `[.]` which unlike `\\.`, should work everywhere (ERE, BRE, pcre, emacs, rex stored in single or double quoted strings, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Use the right tool for the job. You have these 2 expressions:

```c
$i ~ "string"
$NF ~ "\.pdf"
```

but in both cases the patterns are literal strings. So no reason to even bother
with regex matching, just use literal string matching:

```c
index($i, "string")
index($NF, ".pdf")
```

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13

Answer (score 2):

As in many other languages `\x` has a different meaning in strings or in regular expressions.
You can use either

```
$NF ~ /\.pdf/
```

or

```
$NF ~ "\\.pdf"
```

The string `"\.pdf"` is just a strange way of saying `".pdf"`